# Unable to build my Ionic project after installing `ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated`

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I am exploring the firebase post notification. So, I have installed the below packages in my project. After that, I am not able to build my ionic project.

```
$ ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated
$ npm install @ionic-native/fcm
```

I am getting the below error while building my ionic project.

```
> Task :app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug FAILED
35 actionable tasks: 35 executed
D8: Program type already present: android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
> com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives:
  Learn how to resolve the issue at https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#duplicate_classes.
  Program type already present: android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel
```

I have no idea how to solve this error. For your information, I have attached my `package.json` file here.

```
{
  "name": "IonicFristProject",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "https://ionicframework.com/",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@agm/core": "^1.1.0",
    "@angular/animations": "^9.1.9",
    "@angular/cdk": "^8.2.3",
    "@angular/common": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/core": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/material": "^8.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/router": "~8.1.2",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^5.26.0",
    "@ionic-native/fcm": "^5.26.0",
    "@ionic-native/geolocation": "^5.19.0",
    "@ionic-native/google-maps": "^5.5.0",
    "@ionic-native/local-notifications": "^5.26.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic/angular": "^4.11.7",
    "@ionic/lab": "^2.0.18",
    "@ionic/storage": "^2.2.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^11.0.1",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^4.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
    "com.razorpay.cordova": "1.4.10",
    "concurrently": "^5.0.2",
    "cordova-android": "8.1.0",
    "cordova-androidx-build": "^1.0.3",
    "cordova-browser": "6.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-badge": "^0.8.8",
    "cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated": "^7.0.0-beta.3",
    "cordova-plugin-geolocation": "^4.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-googlemaps": "git+https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps.git#multiple_maps",
    "cordova-plugin-local-notification": "^0.9.0-beta.2",
    "cordova-sqlite-storage": "^4.0.0",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "country-state-city": "^1.0.4",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "ionic-angular": "^3.9.9",
    "ionic-selectable": "^4.5.1",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "ng-image-slider": "^2.2.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.1",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.5.4",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/architect": "~0.801.2",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.801.2",
    "@angular-devkit/core": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/cli": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/language-service": "~8.1.2",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "^2.1.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^4.1.3",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.4.2",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.3",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.15.0",
    "typescript": "~3.4.3"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project",
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_ANNOTATIONS_VERSION": "27.+"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": {},
      "cordova-sqlite-storage": {},
      "cordova-plugin-geolocation": {},
      "cordova-plugin-googlemaps": {
        "API_KEY_FOR_ANDROID": "YOUR_ANDROID_API_KEY_IS_HERE",
        "API_KEY_FOR_IOS": "YOUR_IOS_API_KEY_IS_HERE"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-local-notification": {},
      "com.razorpay.cordova": {},
      "cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated": {
        "FCM_VERSION": "19.0.0",
        "GRADLE_TOOLS_VERSION": "3.5.3",
        "GOOGLE_SERVICES_VERSION": "4.3.3",
        "SUPPORT_LIBRARY_VERSION": "28.0.0",
        "ANDROID_DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION_ICON": "@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      }
    },
    "platforms": [
      "browser",
      "android"
    ]
  }
}
```